# A ZFC example of a star-$K$-Menger space which is not star-$K$-Hurewicz

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

1. An open cover $\mathcal U$ of a space $X$ is said to be [$\gamma$-cover](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166864195000674) if $\mathcal U$ is infinite and for each $x\in X$, the set $\{U\in\mathcal U : x\notin U\}$ is finite.
2. A space $X$ is said to be [star-$K$-Menger](https://publi.math.unideb.hu/load_doc.php?p=556&t=pap) if for each sequence $(\mathcal U_n)$ of open covers of $X$ there exists a sequence $(K_n)$ of compact subsets of $X$ such that $\{St(K_n,\mathcal U_n) : n\in\mathbb N\}$ is an open cover of $X$.
3. A space $X$ is said to be [star-$K$-Hurewicz](https://www.doiserbia.nb.rs/img/doi/0354-5180/2017/0354-51801705279S.pdf) if for each sequence $(\mathcal U_n)$ of open covers of $X$ there exists a sequence $(K_n)$ of compact subsets of $X$ such that $\{St(K_n,\mathcal U_n) : n\in\mathbb N\}$ is a $\gamma$-cover of $X$.

It clear that every star-$K$-Hurewicz space is star-$K$-Menger. We are looking for a ZFC example of a star-$K$-Menger space which is not star-$K$-Hurewicz (here, it means without any additional set-theoretic assumption, is there a star-$K$-Menger space which is not star-$K$-Hurewicz?)

Comment: We posted this question on MathOverflow but didn't get any answer (see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/443039/a-zfc-example-of-a-star-k-menger-space-which-is-not-star-k-hurewicz?).

Comment: Are there examples you’re aware of that use assumptions beyond ZFC? Might be useful to add for context.